# Close title window from its child component flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flash-builder

I am implementing a title window, which is calling from the main appication like this

```
protected function sampleButton_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var ttlWndw:SampleTitleWindow = PopUpManager.createPopUp(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication as DisplayObject, SampleTitleWindow, true) as SampleTitleWindow;
                PopUpManager.centerPopUp(ttlWndw);
            }
```

the title window will be this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:TitleWindow xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               xmlns:local="*"
               width="288" height="230">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <local:SampleVBox id="sampleVBox" x="108" y="83"/>
</s:TitleWindow>
```

in the title window i had another child component called sample vbox and this component looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:VBox xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            protected function closeBtn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {

            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>


    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:Button id="closeBtn" label="Close" click="closeBtn_clickHandler(event)"/>
</mx:VBox>
```

My question is, I want to close the title window using the button in the sampleVBox component. please someone help me in this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to dispatch an event from the `SampleVBox` component that the parent `TitleWindow` will listen to. To do this, add some metadata to your `SampleVBox` class that indicates the class dispatches such an event:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:VBox xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Metadata> 
        [Event(name="close", type="flash.events.Event")] 
    </fx:Metadata> 

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            protected function closeBtn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.CLOSE));
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Button id="closeBtn" label="Close" click="closeBtn_clickHandler(event)"/>
</mx:VBox>
```

Now, that the `SampleVBox` declares that it dispatches a "close" event, you can listen for it in the `TitleWindow`:

```
<s:TitleWindow xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               xmlns:local="*"
               width="288" height="230">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            protected function onSampleBoxClose():void
            {
                PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <local:SampleVBox id="sampleVBox" x="108" y="83" close="onSampleBoxClose()"/>
</s:TitleWindow>
```